# When and why to use a 'tick' in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have seen the following is used in an Angular 2 component class:

```
setTimeout(()=>{}, 0);
```

That means, an empty function is called after 0 seconds. I know this is related to Javascript event model, but do not understand it completely.

Please explain when and why this is done in Angular 2, using a small **real world example** with some **code snippet**.

Comment: Can you provide somewhere where you have seen that ?

Comment: I think he wants to know why you would set an empty callback with a zero interval. The arrow function part is incidental.

Comment: Hard to tell withiut seeing in what context this code is used.

Answer (score 16):

```
setTimeout(()=>{}, 0);
```

Causes Angular to run change detection for the whole application, like [ApplicationRef.tick](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ApplicationRef-class.html#!#tick-anchor)

zone.js patches async APIs (`addEventHandler`, `setTimeout`, ...) and runs change detection after a callback was completed.

Comment: Hmm. "tick" is part of the Angular framework, so you'd expect that to behave a certain way. But setTimeout is just plain ol' js and does nothing other than place a callback on the job queue. You seem to be suggesting that change detection is only guaranteed to run if there is a job queue to process, so to ensure it triggers, you just dump an empty callback on the browser job queue? If true, that sounds like A) a huge framework problem and B) a hacky workaround to that problem. I'm dubious of this (as anybody seeing an 0 interval with an empty CB would be).

Comment: @TimConsolazio check my answer, Iain't 100% sure tho

Comment: Can you provide a link to what `tick` you are referring to. No, it's not about the queue, it's about zone.js that patches async APIs and runs change detection after a callback was completed.

Comment: I refer to the tick you post in your comment.

Comment: I see, didn't know how it was implemented :D

Comment: So to be clear...the two should not be seen as having an equivalent effect (or if they do in fact do so, it's incidental). Your answer may need some editing to clarify that one is not just a sub for the other. Again I'm also dubious of setTimeout being a legit way of doing this. I certainly never heard anybody from the angular team suggest it (doesn't mean it's wrong, but not one Angular dev I've ever worked with passed a review to me that had this code, if it did I'd have investigated the hell out of the effect).

Comment: @TimConsolazio I believe setTimeout isn't plain old js, it has been reworked by angular. ie, like in my edited answer.

Comment: setTimeout is plain ol' JS. You might be referring to the $timeout service?

Comment: @TimConsolazio not sure what you mean with "the two". `ApplicationRef.tick()` and `setTimeout(()=>{},0)` are equivalent (if `setTimeout(...)` is run within Angular and therefore within a zone)

Comment: Can you provide a doc stating this? I'm willing to bet this would be something not generally understood at all.

Comment: Perhaps https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html besides that, i'm not aware of docs

Comment: It does indeed say that setInterval has been "monkey patched" in Zones, and that in order to avoid the behavior, you have to actually explicitly say "don't do it," by telling the code to run outside of the zone. 

I'm really curious about this decision. A lot of scripts use setTimeout, and if you bundle them into your app, they'll all trigger change detection now whether or not they should. Could this have unpredictable effects on performance, or even functionality?

Comment: On performance definitly, I don't think on behavior, if code would depend on number of change detection cycles, it's probably best to just purge it ;-), and the patched `setTimeout` should behave the same, except the change detection cycly that is run afterwards

Comment: I agree (I avoid timeouts like the plague). But many do not, and as the OP says, he sees this in components. If this became some kind of generally accepted practice by component developers, thereby working its way into a large codebase where you're expected to reuse code frequently, this could be a problem. And of course, many people reasonably enough would never know it (since it seems like a dicey idea in the first place) and would be alarmed to find it out (as am I). Thanks for the doc.

Comment: It's definitly bad practice and many avoid it anyway. Depending on the concrete use case `Observable.delay` or `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges` could be used instead.

Comment: You can also do it outside the zone (per the zone api). But again, you'd have to know this. I've been to a number of Angular 2 meetups hosted by the Angular team and not once did anybody mention this, even though they did discuss how zones are the new digest.

Comment: Right, there are probably others, but it depends on what exactly you try to accomplish. Yesterday I answered a question about `Promise.resolve().then()...` which might work as well in some scenarios.

Comment: @TimConsolazio Is there any update to this? From what I've read, there's only 2 basic options now: manually trigger CD from top to bottom by using `OnPush`, manually call `tick()` whenever `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError ` pops up. `runOutsideAngular()` is also a manual choice, just not basic.

Answer (score 8):

I'll add on the answer of Gunter as it is small at the moment.

He says :

> `setTimeout(()=>{}, 0);` Causes Angular to run change detection for the whole application

This is because the `setTimeout` method has been monkey patched to be intercepted by angular which upon interception triggers change detection. In other words everytime `setTimeout` is called a change detection happens.

this could be done like this:

```
const temp = window.setTimeout;
window.setTimeout = (...args) => {
    temp(...args)
    angular.triggerChangeDetection(); // or w.e they use
}
```

So the 0 is to make the change detection happen immediately and the empty function is because we don't want to do anything.

Comment: Just to be complete, it seems this is accurate. The behavior of setTimeout has been invisibly altered. For code that takes this into account (so knows when to run the code outside the zone), that may be fine. But imported libs and so on, what is the effect on those? Every single time an interval kicks regardless of its context, change detection will occur? Is that a performance concern, could it have unpredictable behavior in older libs and such? Can you bring angular to it's knees just by calling a few too many empty timeouts?

Comment: @TimConsolazio I think this is a valid concern and while I'm interested with the question, I have no answer for you

Answer (score 3):

I remember asking this question quite some time ago. The response, which was in a github repo called angular-flexslider, was that it's sort of a component-level substitute for `$(document).ready(function() {...}))`.

> Angular manipulates the DOM after the page has loaded. You can sometimes see angular expressions update after the pages have loaded when the CPU is a little busy. The timeout function ensures that the code is run zero milliseconds after angular has finished processing the document.

I've never had to do it, and these days with the component lifecycle hooks I can't imagine you'd ever need to again (that is, if you really ever did need to). But in Angular terms, that's the reason I've seen. I can also say that I have seen a lot of Angular code written by engineers you'd have a very high degree of confidence in (as far as their knowledge of Angular) and never once seen anybody do this.

Also, it is a way of making sure that the code you want to run is placed at the end of the current event loop queue. It's often done for performance. I used to do something like the following for "infinite scrolling" lists (now it's all RxJS, Observables, etc). Consider this code:

```
var res = []
function response ( d ) {
  var chunk = data.splice ( 0, 1000 );

  res = res.concat ( chunk.map ( ...do something ) );

  if ( data.length > 0 ) {
    setTimeout ( () => { response ( data ) }, 0 );
  }
}
```

Because you are recursively calling `response` via the `setTimeout` to process chunks, even though it has a 0 interval, you are doing it in batches, and each of those batches will be processed at the end of the current job queue (instead of just building up a stack of events in the event queue, which would be blocking).

Comment: OP function is empty tho, so it makes little sens. And wasn't there lifecycle hooks back then ? Couldn't it be related to just make one tick pass without doing anything ?

Comment: I've modified my answer to be more complete in terms of not-just-Angular.

Comment: I ultimately have no idea why anybody would set an empty callback on a zero interval. The effect would simply be to put an empty callback at the end of the job queue. I'm not even sure what the JS runtime would do with that in terms of optimization (would it just more or less ignore it?). I can also say that I've seen a lot of Angular code, and a lot of it written by guys you'd expect to know their way around the framework. Not once have I ever seen anybody do an empty callback with 0 interval timeout.

Comment: seems like gunter found out why :p

Comment: Just needed this in a project, where I had to calculate `scrollTop` immediately after the DOM was updated. `ngAfterViewInit`gave the wrong value, and the fix was a 0ms `setTimeout`.